# Close Excel file when error message pops up

Tags: excel, vba

So what this script does is check if file A is opened, if file A is not opened it should display the error message, if the error message displays I would like the Excel file to close.

For some reason, I can't get my head around it. I tried `Application.Quit`, but that just closes everything in Excel, I tried doing just the specific window Excel window for file A, but that seems like a complex problem.

I also tried `Application.ActiveWindow.Close` and `SaveChanges:=False ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` which works best.

My question how to close the Excel after the error message pops up?

```
Sub PullData()

Dim WB As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
    Set WB = Workbooks("A.xlsx")
    If Err Then MsgBox "Text - Text.xlsx Text." & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "" & "Text Text.xlsx Text" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Text" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Text.xlsx Text"

Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("A").Range("A2:AD9999").Copy _
Workbooks("B.xlsm").Worksheets("B").Range("A2")
Worksheets("Text").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="YES"
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to close the workbook the code is in use ThisWorkbook.Close.

Comment: I tried that but If I open file A and then file B which contains the script file B seems to not even open and closes immediately. (The macro runs automatically when the Excel opens)

Comment: Check out this link.  You need to test if the workbook is open first...https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3600-excel-check-if-a-file-is-open.html

Comment: The workbook opens, I have put the `ThisWorkbook.Close` under the `If Err Then MsgBox "Text - Text.xlsx Text."` I suspect that to be the problem? Could someone tell me how to use `ThisWorkbook.Close` in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to close the workbook the code is in when the workbook 'A.xlsx' is not open you can use this.

```vb
 If Err Then 
     MsgBox "A.xlsx not open!"
     ThisWorkbook.Close
 End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe it was so easy, guess I need to give my eyes some rest.